# Cannot remove action noindex in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nofollow, noindex

I've done some research and run up with this code

```
remove_action('wp_head','noindex',1);
```

but apparently it's not removing the `<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow"/>` in my WordPress header. I'm using WordPress 4.2.3

Comment: check out Search Engine Visibility  in admin section in setting >> reading

Comment: @yjs yes I put it on functions.php

Comment: @ash, I want to overwrite the WordPress default function thats why im trying to remove it and add my own set of meta robots

Comment: I have a similar problem, for me even disabling/enabing via admin panel it is rendering `<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [wp_robots](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_robots/) hook introduced in WordPress 5.7.0 to filter its robots meta tag output.

Sample function:

```
add_filter( 'wp_robots', 'wp_robots_remove_noindex', 999 );

function wp_robots_remove_noindex( $robots ){
  
  //put any conditionals here to target certain pages
  if ( is_search() || is_archive(  ) || is_404(  ) ) {

    //set the index and noindex array items
    $robots[ 'index' ] = true;
    $robots[ 'noindex' ] = false;
  }

  return $robots;   
}
```

This results in the following output:
`<meta name='robots' content='index, follow' />`

Answer (score 0):

rankmath  seo use this code
To completely remove the ‘robots’ meta tag you can use the following filter:

`add_filter( 'rank_math/frontend/robots', function( $robots ){return [];
});`
Hope that helps. If you have questions, please ask. We are here to help.
[More read](https://www.findinall.com/blogs/removing-noindex-nofollow-from-my/)

Answer (score -1):

Log in to your WordPress website.

When you're logged in, you will be in your 'Dashboard'.

Click on 'Settings'. On the left-hand side, you will see a menu. ...

Click on 'Reading'. ...

UnCheck 'Discourage search engines from indexing this site'.

Click 'Save Changes'.