# How do I stop Wordpress from inserting a noindex meta tag?

Tags: wordpress, seo, meta-tags, noindex

I'm trying to get my website to be indexed by search engines. According to this, something from Wordpress is injecting a meta tag that's preventing search engines from crawling my site: https://aw-snap.info/file-viewer/?protocol=secure&tgt=chrispokey.com

I'm beginning to think it's something to do with the `wp_head();` function. What next steps can I take to remove the noindex tag that's somehow getting inserted in my website's header section?

Thanks!

```
<?php
    if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    wp_head();
    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please visit `Settings » Reading` and make sure you don't have checkbox checked near the "discourage robots" setting.

Comment: This only allies to the `nofollow` Which is tied to the database's `blog_public` entry -- This does not apply to the `noindex`.