# How to remove noindex meta tag

Tags: wordpress

When I check my WP website's SEO score using Smallseotool dot com, I get this: 
"Your webpage is using the noindex meta tag. This means that your webpage will not be read and indexed by search engines".
How can I remove the noindex meta tag? I'm sure I didn't check "Discourage search engines from indexing this site" in the Reading setting.
Thanks

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51064267/how-do-i-stop-wordpress-from-inserting-a-noindex-meta-tag

Comment: then you need to remove it manually from header.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused. When I check for Google Index, I see my website has been indexed. So the seo signal above was not correct, right?